# 'Tag' object has no attribute 'count' in for loop

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

I am building a BlogApp and I am trying to `create a notification` when a particular `tag` is used 10 times.

So i am using `if statement` in `for loop` so if `any tag used 10 times then create notification` But when i try to `count` then it is showing

> 'Tag' object has no attribute 'count'

models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    post_user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    psot_title = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class Comment(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post_of = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

views.py

```
def page(request):
    subquery = Tag.objects.filter(post__post_user=request.user).annotate(
                                                num_name=Count('name')

    for que in subquery:
        if que.count() > 10:
            Notification.objects.create(user=request.user)

    context = {'subquery':subquery}
    return render(request, 'page.html', context}
```

**What have i tried :-**

I also tried `len` like :-

```
    for que in subquery:
        if len(que) > 10:
            Notification.objects.create(user=request.user)
```

But it showed

> object of type 'Tag' has no len()

I have tried many times by removing `count()` and `len()` but it showed

> 'int' object has no attribute 'name'

If I use `count()` in query then it will count in all tags But i am trying to check every tag.

Any help would be much Appreciated. Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using annotations in your query to add the count information onto the `Tag` object, e.g.

```py
.annotate(num_name=Count('name')
```

This calculates the count of `name` and *annotates* the tag object with that value. To access this count for a given tag, you then need to use:

```
tag.num_name
```

So, in your code:

```
    for que in subquery:
        if que.num_name > 10:
            Notification.objects.create(user=request.user)
```